# Pupose of delegation model in class loader

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I have been reading the classloader concept and i am not clear of why the delegation model is used? Can anyone help me to understand Why the request goes from application classloader-->extension classloader-->bootstrap classloader and then search classes from top to bottom?
Why can't request directly goes to bootstrap classloader and then extension classloader and then application classloader? Can anyone explain with simple understandable explanation?

Answer (score 1):

When a `ClassLoader` *X* delegates to its parent loader *P*, then it will try to resolve the class locally if *P* doesn’t find the class, but this does not imply that there is always a delegation from *P* to *X*.

Only when you ask *X* for a class, you may get a class defined by *X* or its parent *P*, giving precedence to *P* if *X* follows the standard delegation model. If you ask *P* directly you will only get classes defined by *P* (or the parents of *P*), not from *X*. Likewise, when you ask another class loader *Y*, which also has the parent loader *P*, you may get classes defined by *Y* or *P* but not *X*.

In the specific example of the predefined loaders, the bootstrap loader will never ask any other class loader, which is crucial when resolving dependencies of classes loaded by the bootstrap loader. These dependencies of the bootstrap classes can’t get resolved to application classes. Similarly, the dependencies of classes loaded by the extension class loader can get resolved to bootstrap classes or extension classes, but not application classes.

When you create additional class loaders, you can decide which classes are in its scope by choosing the right parent loader. E.g., when the new loader’s parent is the extension class loader, application classes are not in its scope.

Note that this standard parent delegation is a *convention*, in other words, still an implementation detail that not all `ClassLoader` implementations follow. So asking the specific class loader to load a class, is the only way to get the specific class loader’s behavior. At this point, calling from there into the parent loader and returning back to the caller is the simplest way to implement the standard delegation.